# Google Analytics not showing referrer even though utmr is being passed

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any reason why sending utmr as a param is not working? I am just opening this in my browser and everything works correctly except the referrer. This is the code:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.2.5&utmac=UA-421439XX-1&utmhn=mytest.localhost&utms=1&utmn=1036417932&utmcc=__utma%3D197102573.94578827.1376336986.1376336986.1376336986.1%3B&utmp=test&utmcs=-&utmr=www.test.com%2Ftest&utmip=225.15.15.25&utmul=&utmfl=-&utmje=-&utmhid=1624818097
```

If you apply your GA code (on **utmac=**) and open that in your browser you should see the page view in your analytics account. However, the source is 'Direct' even though an utmr is being passed (as it can be seen on **utmr=www.test.com%2Ftest**). Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full URL (you are missing the protocol).